# Docker Toolbox Windows Logging into quay.io

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

When I try to log into my quay.io account using `docker login quay.io` it asks for username but doesn't let me type anything and hangs. Doing some research seems that you have to pass these values in option args for now. So I tried `docker login -u me -p secret -e my@email.com quay.io` and I get

> docker: "login" requires a maximum of 1 argument
>
> Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]

WTF?! Isn't that how I used it?!

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get this working? I was able to successfully log into a docker hub account with the above options and no servername but if I add the servername, I get this error.

Comment: Any chance your secret has a `$` in it or something similar? Try quoting your params.

Comment: Unfortunately that just makes the password prompt pop up as if I didn't even use -p. :(

Comment: @Michael actually double quotes didn't work. Single quotes worked. This was in the docker quickstart terminal.

Answer (score 2):

So my password contained a special character causing it to fail the statement. Once I quoted it it worked great. Double quotes didn't do it, it was single quotes.

Thanks @Michael for the help in the comments!